# multiThreading notify and Wait() concept?

Tags: java

Here is the code for fecthing the primenumbers till 100 and storing them in an array. But the problem is the code is not working properly because the second for loop is not waiting till the i is changed. Can anybody help me to figure out what the problem is?

```
       synchronized (this) {
        boolean stop = false;
        boolean change = false;
        int primenumber[]= new int[20];
        System.out.println("The prime numbers are : ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            change = true;
            notify();
            for (int num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
                if (i % num == 0) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
            if (count == 2) {
                if (!stop) {
                    for (int ab = 0; ab <= 20; ab++) {
                        primenumber[ab] = i;
                        while (!change) {
                            try {
                                wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've set `change` to `true` early in the loop, so `while (!change)` (i.e. `while(!true)`) will never execute its body.

Comment: If you're talking about multithreading, the main problem is that you don't have multiple threads in your code. The wait and notify methods have to be called from different threads.

Answer (score -1):

```
int num = 0;
    System.out.println("Please Enter n.");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();

    System.out.println("\nPrime Numbers up to " + n + ".");

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
            if (i % num == 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        // Counter = 2 means number is only divisible by 1 and the number itself. So it's a prime number.
        if (counter == 2) 
        {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer, include an explanation what your code does and how it addresses the problem of the question.